# Rambam Quote About Books

Tags: rambam, quotations

Where can this quote be found in Rambam: "Do not consider it proof just because it is written in books, for a liar who will deceive with his tongue will not hesitate to do the same with his pen."?

Comment: Internet too. See red text, above.

Comment: if you like an answer, consider marking it correct.

Answer (score 11):

It is a paraphrasing of *Igeres Teman* ([pg. 42](http://books.google.com/books?id=d8MqAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA42&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&sig=ACfU3U2roQXwNX2haqIXdcykuwvLbFkWEg&ci=89%2C153%2C768%2C95&edge=0) in [this edition](http://books.google.com/books?id=d8MqAAAAYAAJ&ots=3ZH80sGGyf&dq=%D7%90%D7%92%D7%A8%D7%AA%20%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%9F&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false)).